# Change font size depending on number of characters and resolution

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I want some script for my app to change the font-size of a title depending on number of characters and the resolution, so to use different font-sizes in the script depending on window resolution and the number of characters of the title.

This is what I have right now:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".boxes.concierto h2.nombreartista span a").each(function () {
 var numChars = $(this).text().length;     
 if ((numChars >= 1) && (numChars < 20)) {
 $(this).css("font-size", "20px");
 }
 else if ((numChars >= 20) && (numChars < 30)) {
 $(this).css("font-size", "18px");
 $(this).css("line-height", "20px");
 }
 else if ((numChars >= 30) && (numChars < 60)) {
 $(this).css("font-size", "15px");
 $(this).css("line-height", "18px");
 }
 else if ((numChars >= 100) && (numChars < 140)) {
 $(this).css("font-size", "0.9em");
 }
 else {
 $(this).css("font-size", "0.8em");
 }          
 });
 });
```

I have tried to add:

```
if($(window).width() >= 1300){
// do your stuff
}
```

at the begining and end of my script but is not working.

Any idea how can I join this two functions correctly?

Thank you so much

Comment: you may want to look into http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: Thank you Dave, I will take a look to Fittextjs. However I prefer to fix manually depending on resolution and characters if is posible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably want to create a condition where either the number of characters or the resolution change the text size.

use the or-operator `||` in your `if` condition

```
if ( ((numChars >= 20) && (numChars < 30)) || $(window).width() >= 1300 ) {
    $(this).css("font-size", "20px");
}
```

#### a better way

the conditions might get quite complex. a better way would be to setup a formula like:

```
var textSize = 1/numChars * $(window).width() * factor;
```

if you want the text size to change in steps you can do something like this:

```
var stepSize = 3;
var steppedTextSize = Math.floor(textSize/stepSize) * stepSize;
```

the `steppedTextSize` will have values in increments of 3. like: 12, 15, 18, ...

Comment: Hello dreamlab. Thank you for your help. What I need is like and "&" opperator so to change number of characters depending on media query resolution. So something like "if media resolution >=1300 do this". I try to change the || operator to & but is not doing anything. Thank you!

Comment: the AND operator is `&&`